# Combine First, Middle Initial, Last name and Suffix in T-SQL (No extra spaces)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel here...I have these four fields:

```
[tbl_Contacts].[FirstName],
[tbl_Contacts].[MiddleInitial],
[tbl_Contacts].[LastName],
[tbl_Contacts].[Suffix]
```

And I want to create a `FullName` field in a view, but I can't have extra spaces if fields are blank...

So I can't do `FirstName + ' ' + MiddleInitial + ' ' + LastName + ' ' + Suffix...` Because if there is no middle initial or suffix I'd have 2 extra spaces in the field.  I think I need a Case statement, but I thought someone would have a handy method for this...Also, the m`iddleinitial` and `suffix` may be null.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming that all columns could be nullable, you can do something like:

```
RTrim(Coalesce(FirstName + ' ','') 
+ Coalesce(MiddleInitial + ' ', '')
+ Coalesce(LastName + ' ', '')
+ Coalesce(Suffix, ''))
```

This relies on the fact that adding to a NULL value yields a NULL.

Answer (score 13):

Whichever options you choose, here's something to think about: this will be a rather involved and thus time consuming option, especially if you have it in a view which gets evaluated each and every time for each and every row in question.

If you need this frequently, I would recommend you add this to your base table as a persisted, computed field - something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Contacts
    ADD FullName AS  (insert the statement of your choice here) PERSISTED
```

When it's persisted, it becomes part of the underlying table, and it's stored and kept up to date by SQL Server. When you query it, you get back the current value *without* incurring the cost of having to concatenate together the fields and determine which to use and which to ignore...

Just something to think about - something that too many DBA's and database devs tend to ignore and/or not know about....

Comment: Never knew about the Persisted keyword. Thanks :-) +1

Comment: I'm a fan of these columns as well. Figure it out once (and if the underlying data changes) and then use it, don't figure it out every time you run the query.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to pass the `FirstName + ' ' + MiddleInitial + ' ' + LastName + ' ' + Suffix` concatenation through the [`REPLACE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function in order to substitute duplicate spaces into a single space.

```
REPLACE(FirstName + ' ' + MiddleInitial + ' ' + LastName + ' ' + Suffix, '  ', ' ')
--                                                                        --    -
```

---

**EDIT:**

Just noticed that some of your fields may be `NULL`, and therefore the above would not work in that case, as the whole string would become `NULL`. In this case, you can use the `COALESCE()` [method as suggested by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699833/combine-first-middle-initial-last-name-and-suffix-in-t-sql-no-extra-spaces/2699864#2699864), but still wrapped it in a `REPLACE()`:

```
REPLACE(RTRIM(COALESCE(FirstName + ' ', '') +
              COALESCE(MiddleInitial + ' ', '') +
              COALESCE(LastName + ' ', '') +
              COALESCE(Suffix, '')), '  ', ' ')
```

Test:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(COALESCE('John' + ' ', '') +
                     COALESCE('' + ' ', '') +
                     COALESCE('Doe' + ' ', '') +
                     COALESCE(NULL, '')), '  ', ' ')

-- Returns: John Doe
```

Comment: You could still use the `REPLACE` function in conjunction with the `ISNULL` function, right?

Answer (score 1):

I had to join Firstname, Middlename, and Lastname. my challenge was to handle NULL values, used following code.

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(@firstname,'') + ' ' + isnull(@middlename,'')) + ' ' + isnull(@lastname,'')))
```

Test different scenarios if you are interested :)

```
DECLARE @firstname VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @middlename VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(MAX)

set @firstname = 'FirstName'
set @middlename = NULL
set @lastname = 'LastName'

SELECT '|'+RTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(@firstname,'') + ' ' + isnull(@middlename,'')) + ' ' + isnull(@lastname,'')))+'|'
--
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SQL Server 2012+` you could use `CONCAT` and `+`:

```
SELECT RTRIM(
       CONCAT(FirstName + ' ', MiddleInitial + ' ', LastName + ' ', Suffix)
      ) AS [FullName]
FROM tbl_Contacts;
```

How it works:

1. If any part of full name is `NULL` then `NULL + ' '` → `NULL`
2. `CONCAT` handles `NULL`
3. In case that after part of name there are only `NULLs`, `TRIM` last space.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/ZIUGUK45403)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_IsNullOrEmpty
(
@vchCheckValue VARCHAR(MAX)
,@vchTrueValue VARCHAR(MAX)
,@vchFalseValue VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

RETURN CASE WHEN NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(@vchCheckValue)),'') IS NULL THEN @vchTrueValue ELSE @vchFalseValue END

END

SELECT FirstName + ' ' + 
       dbo.udf_IsNullOrEmpty(MiddleInitial,'',MiddleInitial + ' ') + 
       LastName + 
       dbo.udf_IsNullOrEmpty(Suffix,'',' ' + Suffix)
FROM tbl_Contacts
```

Answer (score 0):

select CONCAT(IFNULL(FirstName, ''),
            '',
            IFNULL(MiddleName, ''),
            '',
            IFNULL(LastName, '')) AS name
from table

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
select concat(fName,' ', 
    case length(mName) 
    when 0 then '' 
    else concat(mName, ' ') end, lName) as fullName
```

My columns are not null, so this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

create function getfname(@n varchar(30))
returns varchar(30)
as
begin
declare @s varchar(30)
set @s=LEFT(@n,charindex(' ',@n)-1)
return @s
end

create function getLname(@n varchar(30))
returns varchar(30)
as
begin
declare @s varchar(30)

set @s=substring(@n,charindex(' ',@n+1),Len(@n))

return @s
end

Answer (score -2):

the query:

```
SELECT retire.employeehrmsid, 
       Isnull(retire.firstname, '') + ' ' 
       + Isnull(retire.middlename, '') + ' ' 
       + Isnull(retire.lastname, '') AS FullName, 
       retire.dojtoservice, 
       retire.designation, 
       emphistory.currentdoj, 
       emphistory.presentddo, 
       emphistory.office, 
       transfer.generatetid          AS TransferID, 
       transfer.transferdate, 
       transfer.currentlocation, 
       transfer.newlocation, 
       transfer.datas                AS Transfer_Doc, 
       release.generaterid           AS ReleaseID, 
       release.releasedate, 
       release.datar                 AS Release_Doc, 
       employeeserviceupdate.dataeu  AS Join_Doc 
FROM   retire 
       INNER JOIN emphistory 
               ON retire.id = emphistory.id 
       INNER JOIN employeeserviceupdate 
               ON retire.id = employeeserviceupdate.id 
       INNER JOIN transfer 
               ON retire.id = transfer.id 
                  AND emphistory.ehrid = transfer.ehrid 
       INNER JOIN release 
               ON transfer.tid = release.tid
```